# Frontpage slideshow (Joomla) issue

Tags: jquery, joomla, slideshow, frontpage

I installed frontpage slideshow on my joomla site.
I made a category, containing 2 slides.

But the page loads the slides under each other instead of the slide effect.

URL: http://sea-and-wetest.netserver11.net/

Does somebody know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have 2 versions of jQuery running on your site, therefore they are conflicting. Both are being includes externally from googleapis.

For your slider, find out which file contains the jquery embed code and replace with the following:

```
// load jQuery, if not loaded before
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
    JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path/to/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js");
}
```

This will ensure that only 1 copy of jquery is included. Make sure you change the path.

Comment: Note this must go on both places where the jQuery is being loaded to work. Not just one!!

Comment: Okay, now I chaned the module settings so it won't load the jQuery library. But it still doesn't work. I have loaded 1 library now, and that's for the background resizing.

Comment: I'm still seeing 2 being loaded

Comment: ah ok, was just going to say only 1 is being loaded on Chrome but 2 on Firefox for me. However I think there is something wrong with my FF at the moment. anyway, glad it's working now